# Liquidity pool question (probably very dumb)

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv2

My company launched an ERC20 with a Uniswap LP a few years back (2020). They never did anything much with it, and now they want to pull the LP and be done with it. The problem is that nobody in the company knows much about crypto.

My questions are:

Where is the best place to find out exactly how much ETH they will be withdrawing? I'm trying to figure it out, and it appears there may be others who've provided liquidity, but I'm not sure how to tell for sure. How can I tell?

If we pull the LP, will those providers just get their ETH back?

They are sure they've only launched an ETH LP, but there appears to be a USDT pair, too. Does that mean somebody else has launched another pool?

TIA! Sorry if it's an unspeakably stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok! We've all started with zero and it's ok to ask questions that are easy for others.

Anyone is free to create whatever pairs for whichever tokens. If you haven't created other pairs/pools, then other users have created them. Since you haven't created those, you also don't have any LP tokens for those pairs and there's nothing you can do about those pairs.

If you are a LP in a pair, you can withdraw your liquidity at any point you want. Other LPs will just stay in the pool and the pool's liquidity will go down. So you'll get your tokens and Eth, the pool loses some liquidity but otherwise nothing else changes.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to figure out exactly how much Eth and tokens you will get. It also depends on the used Uniswap version. Since you're saying 2020, it's probably v2.

You *can* find out how much you're getting back, but I'm just not that familiar with liquidity pool usage. Someone else can hopefully help you with this part of the question.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's a big help. A lot of it was what I already thought but I'm super unsure about what little I know.

I'm thinking maybe the only way to know for sure might be for them to connect the wallet Ledger and give it a go. If anybody else knows, that would be great.

By the way, it was definitely V2.